# iOS - Twitter Connectivity Issue: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

I am creating an app displaying my twitter timeline. But I sometimes get the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x1fd807c0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

I am using the following code to retrieve the timeline of twitter:

```
-(void) getTimeLine{

ACAccountStore *account=[[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType=[account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
[activityIndicatorLoadTweets setHidden:NO];
[activityIndicatorLoadTweets startAnimating];
[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
{
    if (granted==YES) {
        NSArray *arrOfAccounts=[account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
        if ([arrOfAccounts count]!=0)
        {
            ACAccount *twitterAccount=[arrOfAccounts lastObject];
            NSURL *requestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json"];
            NSMutableDictionary *params=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [params setObject:@"20" forKey:@"count"];
            [params setObject:@"1" forKey:@"include_entities"];

            SLRequest *postRequest=[SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestURL parameters:params];

            postRequest.account=twitterAccount;

            [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
            {
                if (responseData==nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Could not connect. Try Again.");
                    [self showLabelAndStartTimer];
                    lblStatus.text=@"Could not connect at the moment. Please try Again.";
                    [activityIndicatorLoadTweets setHidden:YES];
                    [activityIndicatorLoadTweets stopAnimating];
                }
                else{
                    lblStatus.hidden=YES;
                    self.arrDataSource=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

                    if ([self.arrDataSource count]!=0)
                    {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                        {
                            [self.tableTweetsView reloadData];
                            [activityIndicatorLoadTweets setHidden:YES];
                            [activityIndicatorLoadTweets stopAnimating];
                            //[self fetchBollyTweetsFrom:self.arrDataSource];
                        });
                    }
                }

            }];

        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Failure to access acount. Please check your internet connection.");
        [activityIndicatorLoadTweets setHidden:YES];
        [activityIndicatorLoadTweets stopAnimating];
    }


}];

}
```

Please note that the error description is from the line:

```
self.arrDataSource=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
```

The error is mostly self explanatory but If my JSON is wrong, why I am getting successful response half of the time?
Comments and suggestions on the code are also welcome as I am newbie in iOS programming and using JSON.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

connections to api.twitter.com has been restricted to TLS/SSL connections only. If your application still uses HTTP plaintext connections you will need to update it to use HTTPS connections
check this link : https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to get the full JSON string and know the reason behind your error:

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData 
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", newStr);
self.arrDataSource=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry, just a typing mistake :)

Comment: Json is printed correctly when I get successful result. But the issue is that I am still getting intermittent results. I am expecting an explanation for this behaviour.

Comment: can you post a sample of the printed JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is calling version 1 of the Twitter API which was [officially retired on June 11, 2013](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-retirement-final-dates). You should be using [v1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1).

Comment: Thanks, so from now I should use the following url: http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json . Just a question, why the old url is also giving me successful response most of the time?

Comment: It's because you're calling the non-HTTPS version of the API. It seems Twitter has not turned that off just yet. You should be using v1.1 and HTTPS for all Twitter API calls.

Comment: I have updated the Url. But this is not the source of problem because I am still getting intermittent results.